# jQuery remove entire script with specific data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to remove the entire script (or disable it) using jQuery that has `cookieconsent-level="tracking"` ?

```
<script type="text/plain" cookieconsent-level="tracking">
  google analytics code
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the script element using an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$("[cookieconsent-level='tracking']").remove();
```

...but you can't remove the effects of the code it contained. Once a `script` element with inline content has been added to the DOM by the parser, the script it contains has **already** been run. Removing the element has no effect whatsoever on the code. (Unlike, say, removing a `link` or `style` element, which does affect the CSS.)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can do it like this using jquery:

```
$('[cookieconsent-level="tracking"]').remove()
```

BUT it will not undo that google tracking has already done something! You Should do an opt-in solution where you ADD Google Analytics IF tracking is allowed.

Comment: You can, but A) Not like that, and B) It won't accomplish anything. (Edit: Ah, you slipped in a ninja edit.)